# Conditional probabilities textbook confusion

Tags: probability

> An electronic fuse is produced by five production lines. All five production lines produce fuses at the same rate and normally produce only 2% defective fuses. Unfortunately, production line 1 suffered mechanical difficulties and produced 5% defectives during a certain period of time. A customer received fuses during this time and tested 3 fuses. One failed.

Let $B$ denote that event that a fuse was drawn from line 1 and $A$ denote the event that a fuse was defective. My textbook says $P(A|B) = 3 \cdot (0.05) \cdot (0.95)^2$. I don't understand this in the slightest. The probability of drawing a defective fuse from line 1 is $0.05$, and you draw 3 times, but I still don't understand that expression. How did they obtain it?

Comment: One fused, it fused with probability $0.05$. The other two did not fuse, that happened with probability $0.95 \times 0.95$. There are three ways to choose the fused bulb, hence the answer is the product of these three, which is given.